# Android its Possible keyboard above in bottom layout?

Tags: android

[image]

When i write some text in Edittext i want to Keyboard above to Bottomlayout(Three button Home,contact,logout),Its possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible, http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Quote: **The soft keyboard is positioned at the bottom of the screen over the application's window.**

As it is on the bottom, there can be nothing below it.